# JPA OneToMany , how to ignore field ManyToOne when print in console or webapp

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have 2 tables: genres(genre_id, genre_name) and movies (movie_id, movie_name, movie_score, genre_id). genre_id_fk from movies referenced to genre_id in genres.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "genres", schema = "test")
public class Genre {

@Id
@Column(name = "genre_id")
private int id;
@Column(name = "genre_name")
private String name;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "genre", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and 2nd entity for movies

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "movies", schema = "test")
public class Movie {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "movie_id")
private int id;
@Column(name = "movie_name")
private String name;
@Column(name = "movie_score")
private double score;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "genre_id")
private Genre genre;
}
```

when i am trying to print it in console with this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pu");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    Genre genre = em.find(Genre.class, 1);
    System.out.println(genre);
}
```

receiving `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError`
only removing from toString() in movie class field "genres" can fix it. But is it possible to avoid it?
And same problem with spring boot application

```
@RestController
public class GenreController {

@Autowired
private GenreService genreService;

@RequestMapping("/test/{id}")
public List<Genre> getGenreInfo(@PathVariable int id){
    return genreService.getGenreFilms(id);
}
}
```

here service

```
@Service
public class GenreService {

public List<Genre> getGenreFilms(int id){
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pu");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    List<Genre> genres = new ArrayList<>();
    Genre genre = em.find(Genre.class, id);
    genres.add(genre);
    return genres;
}
}
```

and receiving this problem like:
[{"id":1,"name":"Thriller","movies":[{"id":1,"name":"Any, are you ok?","score":5.45,"genre":{"id":1,"name":"Thriller","movies":[{"id":1,"name":"Any, are you ok?","score":5.45,"genre":{"id":1,"name":"Thriller","movies":[{"id":1,"name":"Any, are you ok?","score":5.45,"genre":....
and to infinity with sof exception. Console i can fix just with ignoring field in toString() method. But how to fix this problem in webapplication?

here hibernate debug log when console print

```
22:15:37.154 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - 
Resolving associations for [com.company.Genre#1]
22:15:37.164 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Done 
materializing entity [com.company.Genre#1]
22:15:37.164 [main] DEBUG 
org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl - 
HHH000387: ResultSet's statement was not registered
22:15:37.165 [main] DEBUG 
org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader - Done 
entity load : com.company.Genre#1
22:15:37.165 [main] DEBUG 
org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl - 
Initiating JDBC connection release from afterTransaction
22:15:37.167 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer 
- Loading collection: [com.company.Genre.movies#1]
22:15:37.167 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select movies0_.genre_id as 
genre_id4_1_0_, movies0_.movie_id as movie_id1_1_0_, movies0_.movie_id as 
movie_id1_1_1_, movies0_.genre_id as genre_id4_1_1_, movies0_.movie_name as 
movie_na2_1_1_, movies0_.movie_score as movie_sc3_1_1_ from test.movies 
movies0_ where movies0_.genre_id=?
Hibernate: select movies0_.genre_id as genre_id4_1_0_, movies0_.movie_id as 
movie_id1_1_0_, movies0_.movie_id as movie_id1_1_1_, movies0_.genre_id as 
genre_id4_1_1_, movies0_.movie_name as movie_na2_1_1_, movies0_.movie_score 
as movie_sc3_1_1_ from test.movies movies0_ where movies0_.genre_id=?
22:15:37.168 [main] DEBUG 
org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl - 
Preparing collection intializer : [com.company.Genre.movies#1]
22:15:37.170 [main] DEBUG 
org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl - 
Starting ResultSet row #0
22:15:37.171 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.CollectionReferenceInitializerIm 
pl - Found row of collection: [com.company.Genre.movies#1]
22:15:37.171 [main] DEBUG 
org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl - 
Starting ResultSet row #1
22:15:37.172 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.CollectionReferenceInitializerIm 
pl - Found row of collection: [com.company.Genre.movies#1]
22:15:37.172 [main] DEBUG 
org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl - 
Starting ResultSet row #2
22:15:37.172 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.CollectionReferenceInitializerIm 
pl - Found row of collection: [com.company.Genre.movies#1]
22:15:37.172 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - 
Resolving associations for [com.company.Movie#1]
22:15:37.172 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Done 
materializing entity [com.company.Movie#1]
22:15:37.173 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - 
Resolving associations for [com.company.Movie#2]
22:15:37.173 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Done 
materializing entity [com.company.Movie#2]
22:15:37.173 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - 
Resolving associations for [com.company.Movie#3]
22:15:37.173 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Done 
materializing entity [com.company.Movie#3]
22:15:37.173 [main] DEBUG 
org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext - 1 collections 
were found in result set for role: com.company.Genre.movies
22:15:37.173 [main] DEBUG 
org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext - Collection 
fully initialized: [com.company.Genre.movies#1]
22:15:37.173 [main] DEBUG 
org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext - 1 collections 
initialized for role: com.company.Genre.movies
22:15:37.173 [main] DEBUG 
org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl - 
HHH000387: ResultSet's statement was not registered
22:15:37.173 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer 
- Done loading collection
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

tell me where i am doing wrong and how to fix or google this problem? just not print this object by localhost:8080/genre/id? make something particular print or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you have an infinite recursion when trying `toString` your `Genre` entities. Your code first loads your Genre entity by id, and then calls `Genre.toString()`. Because you have `@OneToMany` relationship with `Movie`s, it `lazy loads` the list and then calls `Movie.toString()` for every movie related to the genre. Then for every movie you have a `@ManyToOne` relationship back with Genre. And here lies the problem. It will call again `Genre.toString()` for each movie in the list.

### Possible solutions

1. If you only want to  simply print it in console, do not include movies list in `Genre.toString()`
2. If you are using Jackson, add `@JsonBackReference` to your `@ManyToOne` relationship in `Movie`, this way Jackson will ignore it when mapping to Json
   [Annotation documentation here](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonBackReference.html)
3. If using DTOs, just do not include `Movie` property in your DTO.

Hope this helps.